# Sheevuh mayoys, sheeveem vawshevuh (777) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

Who knows 777 in the Torah?

Blessings and success

Comment: How is it possible that anyone can even think of conceiving to contemplate the thought of downvoting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The age Lemech lived until.

[Bereishis 5:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.5.31?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> וַֽיְהִי֙ כָּל־יְמֵי־לֶ֔מֶךְ **שֶׁ֤בַע וְשִׁבְעִים֙ שָׁנָ֔ה וּשְׁבַ֥ע מֵא֖וֹת שָׁנָ֑ה** וַיָּמֹֽת׃ (ס)
>
> All the days of Lemech came to **777 years**; then he died.